# Highcharts Solid Gauge Width

Tags: highcharts

I've not found an API or previous question that addresses changing the width of the solid gauge data plot.

I can easily change the chart width, plot width, plot padding, arc background's inner and outer widths... but not the chart.

How do I prevent the chart (green) from overlapping the background (white)?
*(Just created account, so can't insert images yet)*

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtvekgi9uyxvpww/arc.png

```
pane: {
  center: ['50%', '70%'],
  size: '130%',
  startAngle: -90,
  endAngle: 90,
  background: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    innerRadius: '75%',
    outerRadius: '100%',
    shape: 'arc',
    borderColor: 'transparent'
  }
},
```

Adjusting the '130%' doesn't solve the issue.

UPDATE::: http://jsfiddle.net/jm8E4/3/

Thanks

Comment: Can you post code in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: updated, thanks for reminding me. @Sameer

Comment: in short you want to set width of chart(green) same as backgrounf(white).?? am i right?

Comment: @Sameer that is correct

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use innerRadius on yAxis.

```
plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            innerRadius: '75%',
            dataLabels: {
                y: -45,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
 },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jm8E4/6/

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

**EDITED**

i have changed `innerradius` and `outerradius`

```
       background: {
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc',
            borderColor: 'transparent'
        }
```

create chart with `innerRadius` same as `outerRadius`

`outerRadius` is the background radius on which chart will shown and `innerRadius` is chart radius.

**Demo**
[Edited Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jm8E4/7/)

Comment: This isn't what I want. I want to keep the background (white) as a thinner arc. The green is what needs to change so that it is the same thinness as the white.

Comment: Still not it. Check the accepted answer for what I was looking for. Thanks for attempting though.